# JTable: change traversal order

Tags: java, swing, jtable, traversal

I want to traverse horizontally through a JTable, when pressing enter. I've tried with `JTable.changeSelection` but it doesnt seem to work. Any ideas how to change the traversal behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read up on [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/). You would want to "*share an Action with a different KeyStroke*"

Answer (score 3):

Enter is vertical traverse , TAB is horisontal, just hold Enter event and generate Tab event or call function for Tab Event. But you should set up next properties:

```
            table.setSelectionMode(
                    ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```

Comment: It was the additional code from my class, sorry I have copied and did not check it, currently edited ...

Comment: -1 for the detour - sure I could travel from Berlin to Amsterdam via Moskau-Peking-SanFranscisco ...

Answer (score 1):

```
JTable.getInputMap(JInternalFrame.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF _FOCUSED_COMPONENT)
.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "SOME_ACTION");
JTable.getInputMap(JInternalFrame.WHEN_FOCUSED)
.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "SOME_ACTION");

JTable.getActionMap().put("SOME_ACTION", actions);


actions = new AbstractAction() {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
//This action will get fired on Enter Key
}
};
```

Comment: The code is not in the right order. Also, the first line is broken. Some explanation would probably help the OP.